# Why isnt my nested loop not looping Diagonal for checking if Tic-tac-toe is win(with java)?

Tags: java

im a student who really needs help(my teacher doesn't even answer when i email her, i am a online student)
So, i have a tic-tac-toe program(the program is to long to put all of it here, 10 classes at least 5 of them have 300 lines of code)
So in this program there is a method isWin(), it will check the tic-tac-toe if there is a win so it will check Horizontally, Vertically, and diagonally from both sides.
So the problem is with diagonally checking if there is a win. Im going to post the full isWin() function and what i tried.

```
  boolean isWin(char mark) {
        // If the game has already been recorded as won, return true.
        if (gameHasBeenWon) return true;
        /**
         * Using the incoming mark, implement nested loops to loop through the
         * columns and diagonals, checking each character in every column and
         * diagonal o see if there are three marks in a line. If any
         * winning line is found, complete the following directives:
         *   1. Set gameHasBeenWon to true.
         *   2. Return the value of gameHasBeenWon. 
         *
         * The check for horizontal wins is provided for you.
         */
        // Check for horizontal wins.
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            boolean win = true;
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] != mark) win = false;
            }
            if (win) {
                gameHasBeenWon = true;
                return gameHasBeenWon;
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            boolean win = true;
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                if (grid[row][col] != mark) win = false;
            }
            if (win) {
                gameHasBeenWon = true;
                return gameHasBeenWon;
            }
        }
         for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            boolean win = true;
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            if (grid[row][col] != mark) win = false;
            if(row ==
            }
        }
```

What i tried to do is

```
for (int col = 0; col < 1; col++) {
            boolean win = true;
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                if(row == 2){
                if (grid[row][col+2] != mark) win = false;
            }else if(row==0){
                if (grid[row][col] != mark) win = false;
            }else{
                if (grid[row][col+1] != mark) win = false;
            }
            if (win) {
                gameHasBeenWon = true;
                return gameHasBeenWon;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when i tried that, the isTied() method doesn't work, i will provide that under.

```
 boolean  isTie() {
        // If game has already been recorded as won, then it cannot be a tie.
        if (gameHasBeenWon) return false;

        // If there are any spaces on the board, return false, because it is
        // not a tie.
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == SPACE) return false;
            }
        }

        // If the game was not won, but all the spaces are full, it is a tie.
        return true;
    }
```

Edit: this is the Tester class

```
/**
 * The following is a short program that tests the coding of class
 * TicTacToeBoard from Lab Exercise 2.
 */
public class TicTacToeBoardTest2 {
    /**
     * Use the special main method for testing the TicTacToeBoard class only.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\nTicTacToeBoard test 2 results:");
        
        TicTacToeBoard testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            testBoard.move(1, 1, 'X');
            testBoard.move(2, 2, 'O');
            testBoard.move(2, 0, 'X');
            System.out.println();  
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Not a win", !testBoard.isWin('X'));
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }
        
        testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            testBoard.move(2, 0, 'X');
            testBoard.move(2, 1, 'X');
            testBoard.move(2, 2, 'X');
            System.out.println();
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Horizontal win", testBoard.isWin('X'));
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }
        
        testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            testBoard.move(0, 1, 'O');
            testBoard.move(1, 1, 'O');
            testBoard.move(2, 1, 'O');
            System.out.println();  
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Vertical win", testBoard.isWin('O'));
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }

        testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            testBoard.move(0, 0, 'X');
            testBoard.move(1, 1, 'X');
            testBoard.move(2, 2, 'X');
            System.out.println();
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Diagonal win 1", testBoard.isWin('X'));
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }
        
        testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            testBoard.move(0, 2, 'X');
            testBoard.move(1, 1, 'X');
            testBoard.move(2, 0, 'X');
            System.out.println();
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Diagonal win 2", testBoard.isWin('X'));
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }
        
        testBoard = new TicTacToeBoard();
        try {
            char[] marks = {'O', 'O', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'O', 'O', 'X', 'X'};
            int index = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                    testBoard.move(row, col, marks[index]);
                    index++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            testBoard.display();
            printMessage("Tie game not a win", !testBoard.isWin('X'));
            printMessage("Tie game", testBoard.isTie());
        } catch (IllegalMoveException ime) {
            System.out.println("Error: illegal move not expected: " + ime);
        }
    }
    
    private static void printMessage(String testCase, boolean passed) {
        System.out.println(testCase + "? " + passed);
        if (passed) {
            System.out.println("Good: " + testCase + " handled.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error: " + testCase + " not handled.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about it this way. You're looking for a solution to horizontal, vertical, diagonal from 0,0 to 2,2, diagonal from 2,0 to 0,2. These are 4 different directions and should have 4 different solutions.

Comment: yes @Zachary i have realized that from this morning lol, but how do i get only [0,0 ], [1,1], [2,2] excluding the others( [1,0], [0,1] etc) Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try Googling for the words **java tic tac toe**? Many people have implemented the game and posted their code online. See hoe they did it and compare with your code.

Answer (score 1):

When you move diagonally you are changing the coordinates for `row` and for `col` at the same time. So you can't build loops where one of these coordinates are not changing. Also you have to check both directions, going "down" from `[0,0]` to `[2,2]` (assuming `[0,0]` is the top left corner) and going "up" from `[2,0]` to `[0,2]`. For the part going "down" you can write a `for` loop like this:

```
win = true;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (grid[i][i] != mark) { // this will check [0,0], [1,1], [2,2]
        win = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

For going "up" you have to decrease the `row` index like this:

```
win = true;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (grid[2-i][i] != mark) { // this will check [2,0], [1,1], [0,2]
        win = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but that will return true in all cases  where there is a mark so when there is no win yet it still sends true and the isTie() is not working too. I will add the Test class maybe you can see what i mean.

Comment: It depends on how exactly you are adding these code snippets to your code how they work for you. But the variable `win` will contain the value `true` when the diagonal is filled with values of the given `mark` variable (and `false` if it doesn't).